# Will I lose image quality when editing and re-saving an existing png file?

Tags: png, compression

I know that each time a `.jpg` file is saved, it is compressed and loses quality.

Is the same true for `.png` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While being compressed a png image still is lossless. If you change parts of your image and re-save the quality of the image is still the same!

Sources:

- long personal experience
- [german Wikipedia-page](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) (to be extra sure)

Comment: though it depends on how you've saved it. If it was an 8-bit png, and you edit it adding color outside the compressed pallet, colors may shift as it gets resaved.

Answer (score 1):

You could. Depends on how you re-save it. I would select png24 8bit. That will keep the quality high.